# GridView on page won't refresh, even when calling DataBind again

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

All the research I've done seems to indicate that if I simply call `DataBind()` again then my `GridView` will get updated. This only seems to be the case if I'm debugging and stepping through my code, the `GridView` refreshes fine. However, if I don't step through my code while running the app in debug mode, the `btnFileImport_Click` method below doesn't refresh my `GridView`. Could it have anything to do with the fact that I'm updating the data the `GridView` uses by loading a file using an SSIS package? Below is the code behind:

```
namespace InternationalWires
{
    public partial class Default_Corporate : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection
        (
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ["InternationalWiresConnection"].ToString()
        );
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlServerAgent sqlAgent = new SqlServerAgent();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindRatesGrid();
            }
        }
        public void BindRatesGrid()
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection
            (
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                ["InternationalWiresConnection"].ToString()
            );
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spGetRates", conn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            grdRates.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            grdRates.DataBind();
        }
        protected void btnFileImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the filename and path from the user.
            // Must be in UNC format or SSIS will fail.
            string filename =
                Path.GetFullPath(fileSelect.PostedFile.FileName);
            // Update the settings table to the value from above.
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection
                (
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                    ["InternationalWiresConnection"].ToString()
                );
                cmd = new SqlCommand
                (
                    "UPDATE Settings SET settingValue = '" + filename +
                    "' WHERE settingName = 'SSISRatesImportFile'", conn
                );
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                // To do: handle exceptions.
            }
            finally 
            {
                if (conn != null) conn.Dispose();
                if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
            }
            // Set the name of the SSIS package to run.
            sqlAgent.SSISName = ConfigurationManager
                .AppSettings["ratesImportPackage"].ToString();
            // Start the job.
            sqlAgent.SQL_SSISPackage();
            // Do nothing while waiting for job to finish.
            while (sqlAgent.SQL_IsJobRunning()) { }
            if (sqlAgent.SQL_JobSucceeded())
            { 
                lblStatus.Text = "Import Succeeded";
                BindRatesGrid();
            }
            else
            { 
                lblStatus.Text =
                "Import Failed. " + 
                "Please contact IT for failure details on SSIS import package."; 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your `// TO DO: handle exceptions` is the reason why the GridView does not get updated ;-)

Comment: When I step through the code it never hits the exceptions, so I'm not sure why that would be.

Comment: Adding some code into that section didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much banging of my head on the desk, I finally stumbled across the answer in a roundabout way.

My `SQL_IsJobRunning` and `SQL_JobSucceeded` methods use `sp_help_job` in SQL to figure out whether or not the job is still running, and whether or not it succeeded. I was working on the success/error messages to display in my label and when I was getting the wrong ones I realized that the 'current_execution_status' was showing the job was done, but the 'last_run_outcome' had not yet been updated by the time my code was looking at the value. So I put a pause `(Thread.Sleep(4000))` in between the two methods to give the database a chance to log the `last_run_outcome` before I checked it.

This solved my label error message issue, and had the pleasant side effect of also solving my `GridView` problem. With the pause in place the `GridView` also updates successfully. There must have been something happening too fast for the `GridView` to update properly. I just wish I knew what. Perhaps the `BindRatesGrid()` method was being run before he data was committed in the database.

```
// Do nothing while waiting for job to finish.
while (sqlAgent.SQL_IsJobRunning()) {}
Thread.Sleep(4000);
if (sqlAgent.SQL_JobSucceeded())
{ 
    lblStatus.Text = "Import Succeeded";
    BindRatesGrid();
}
else
{ 
    lblStatus.Text = "Import Failed. " +
    "Please contact IT for failure details on SSIS import package."; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting your grid into an Update Panel. It looks like when you click the button, the page isn't refreshed in the postback thus the grid isn't...

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but apparently FileUpload doesn't play nicely with UpdatePanel.  I'm not having much luck.