# How to display the result of SSIS in web page?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ssis, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create a web page in asp.net mvc 5 application.In that, I need to excute a SSIS package and that package will give some rows(from database or excel or text file) as output and that finally that output I should display in my web page gridview(or model class). I am using following code to execute a ssis package:

```
DTSExecResult pkgResults;
using (var pkg = new Application().LoadPackage(servicePath, null))
{
    pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
}
```

Help me to display the output of SSIS package in the web page in mvc 5.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at this hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200048/gridview-on-page-wont-refresh-even-when-calling-databind-again

Comment: I don't know of any way that packages can give rows as output to an application.  The package should copy rows to a destination (table or file) and then you can do a query or readfile to get the rows from there.

Comment: Is SSIS running on the same machine? And if so which version of SSIS are you using?

Comment: Both cases are possible . I am using SSIS 2012